# setlocale и linux

Tags: c++, linux

Пишу на линуксе и никогда не в код не вставляю:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
```

При этом символы кирилицы выводятся без проблем. Под виндой в этом случае выведет кракозябры? Почему под линуксом все в порядке?

Comment: Если вы под Виндой будете в редакторе писать в той же кодировке, в которой работает консоль - никаких проблем не будет. Лично я консольные приложения пишу в 866 кодировке, чтобы с этими локалями не заморачиваться...

Comment: Потому что в линуксе кодировка консоли видимо та же, что и для остальных приложений. А в Windows она для совместимости с древним софтом оставлена другой. Строго говоря, setlocale не избавляет от всех проблем с национальными алфавитами (только переход в режим UTF-16 обеспечивает это). Уже много копий поломано на обсуждениях этой темы.

Comment: потому что c++ изначально предлагался для windows

Comment: Как интересно. А не подскажите, как это с++ умудрился появится раньше виндоус, для которой он "предлогался"?

Comment: C++ — язык программирования общего назначения, синтаксис которого основан на языке C.. Это не просто так написано...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема не в операционной системе, а в терминале. Стандартный cmd работает в кодировке 866, при этом попытка настроить локали для вывода строк из исходников приводит к тому, что ввод и вывод начинают работать в разных кодировках (если ввод кириллицы не нужен - setlocale решает проблему). Более-менее рабочим решением является правильная настройка локалей для последовательности ввод-вывод, и сохранение исходников в соответствующей кодировке.

В PowerShell ситуация вроде бы немного лучше, его хотя бы можно настроить для кириллицы, но по умолчанию он тоже плохо с ней работает.